# Constructor injection does not work with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I got the error below when I tried to use constructor injection in LoginController.php

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [Domain\User\UserService] does not exist.
```

Any idea why?
Following are details.

LoginController.php

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    private $userService;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;


    public function __construct(UserService $userService)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
```

UserService.php

```
namespace Domain\User;

class UserService
{
    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct(IUserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

}
```

UserRepository.php

```
class UserRepository implements IUserRepository
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
```

UserRepositoryServiceProvider.php

```
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            IUserRepository::class,
            function ($app) {
                return new UserRepository($app->make(User::class));
            }
        );
    }
```

UserServiceProvider.php

```
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            'UserService',
            UserService::class
        );
    }
```

Comment: how does the autoloader know about this class? this isn't an issue with the container, its with autoloading that class, it doesn't exist because it hasn't been loaded

Comment: You are saying there is no problem with my setting according to DI?

Comment: I use composer and I thought this should do the trick for autoloading classes. I already tried `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: it doesn't scan your whole project ... you have to decide how you want to autoload this, I would suggest PSR4 autoloading

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I will dig into that :)

Comment: Seems like this is not a problem with autoload. The error obviously occurred when Laravel tries to bind the abstract class to the concrete one.

Comment: trying creating an instance of the class yourself and you will see that it doesn't exist

Comment: I see. Can you give me the example about how should I change `composer.json` so Laravel can recognize the classes I added with the namespace "Domain"?

Comment: ```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Domain\\": "Domain/"
        },
```

This solved the problem! Thanks!!!